# Jquery table to Excel is not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, excel

I am using below code to export my table to Excel.

It is working fine in Chrome, but it's not working in Firefox and IE.

```
$("#exportButton").click(function(e) {
        var table_div = document.getElementById('availablePeopleTable');
        var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
        a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
        a.download = 'Availability_Report_' + postfix + '.xls';
        //triggering the function
        a.click();
        //just in case, prevent default behaviour
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: **[This link](http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/jWAJ7/light/)** has some demo which works both in `firefox` and `IE`.. Bdw what version of `FF` and `IE` you are using??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao could you post this as an answer?

Comment: But without OP accepting that its working for her I cannot post it! what if it does not work for her?? @ShubhamBhave